# Uninstalling vim vundle package manager

Tags: vim, vi, vundle

I've installed vundle (git cloned) vim vundle package manager. It seems like I was not even able to install a single plugins. I would like to uninstall it and start fresh with vim. Any suggestions?

Comment: `rm -rf $HOME/.vim && rm $HOME/.vimrc`?

Answer (score 8):

Remove this from your ~/.vimrc:

```
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle/
call vundle#rc()
```

And then remove the ~/.vim directory